# Websockets with Nginx and certbot

Tags: php, node.js, nginx, websocket, lets-encrypt

Somewhat I am lost with the configuration. Followed many articles and still can't connect to wss.

##### Nginx conf.d/my_wss.conf

```
server {
server_name wss.example.com;

location / {
    proxy_pass   http://localhost:9944;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header   Host   $host;
    proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header   Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header   Connection "upgrade";
}

listen 443 http2 ssl;
listen [::]:443 http2 ssl;
ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/wss.example.com/fullchain.pem;
ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/wss.example.com/privkey.pem;
}
```

#### node server.js

```js
const server = new https.createServer({
   cert: fs.readFileSync('/etc/letsencrypt/live/wss.example.com/cert.pem'),
   keys: fs.readFileSync('/etc/letsencrypt/live/wss.example.com/privkey.pem')
});
const websocketServer = new WebSocketServer({server});

websocketServer.on('connection', (ws, request) => {
    ws.on('close', () => {
        
    });

    ws.on('message', (data, isBinary) => {
        
    });
});

server.listen(9944);
```

#### browser client.js

```js
websocket = new WebSocket(`wss://wss.example.com`);
websocket.onclose = event => {
    console.log(event.code) // 106
};
```

And unfortunately browser does not want to connect throwing 106 error.
I've installed `wscat` on the server to connect to wss
but it gives me output as follows:

```
$ wscat -c wss://localhost:9944
error: write EPROTO 140551547832256:error:14094410:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:sslv3 alert handshake failure:../deps/openssl/openssl/ssl/record/rec_layer_s3.c:1565:SSL alert number 40

$ wscat -c wss://wss.example.com
error: Unexpected server response: 502
```

Where did I mess up?

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that you have already configured TLS termination at nginx. Shouldn't you also configure it on your node server?

Comment: can you maybe explain a bit more what you mean? Cause I am newbie to SSL :)

Comment: You can try to create a normal HTTP server (`const server = http.createServer`). The connection from NGINX to the Node server should be HTTP, while the connection from clients to NGINX should be HTTPS. The declaration of `ssl_certificate` and `ssl_certificate_key` in the NGINX config is called TLS termination.